# Flaw on VBA Variable Execution

Tags: vba, excel, executequery

Good Afternoon StackOverflow gang,

I'm currently in the process of fully automating my VBA script, however I've hit a slight bump. The following portion of my script take the date in a specific cell, and translates it farther down the script. The purpose of this portion of the script is to fully run the other macros below when it detects a change that has been made to the cell. It works on first run, but deletes the date located in A1 the second time I make a change to it. Any thoughts as to why this is occurring, or has anyone found structural errors when looking at this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'to prevent endless loop

    Call Execute

    MsgBox "The Date Has Changed!"

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you post code for `execute`.

Comment: No, but you have left out the code for the sub "Execute". If you can share that, we may have more insight.

Comment: No worries, that code is governing the execution of two other macros. Those two execute fine when I tested it, to my knowledge

Comment: Sub Execute()

transfercsv
CSV_Ingest

End Sub

Comment: @Kyle If you need more of the script, let me know

Comment: We need to see all the code. There is nothing in the code posted that will clear cell contents, so it has to be somewhere else. Please post all the code run when the worksheet changes.

Comment: No worries @Kyle, the code is as follows:

Comment: The Execute routine is the one guilty, check there, there's nothing stated in the worksheet change that could trigger that behavior

Comment: @Kyle It was too long, heres a link to it in pasteco... http://pasted.co/7abc39ca